# How to show web page in android in android app only

Tags: android, android-webview

I want to show any webpage in my app only, not in browser.
I have used the below code, but it opens the browser.

```
web = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.web_vieww);
web.loadUrl("http://www.google.co.in/");
```

Comment: you should set WebViewClient for webview with overriding `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` by with webview avoid to open default browser on redirection or any link click or change of webview url

Comment: I have used this also but not working... web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

      @Override
      public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
      {
       url="http://www.google.co.in";
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
      }
  });

Comment: Not working means? because same is working fine when i'm trying

Comment: this open browser........ I want that this URL should open in the app.......let say I want to show webpage in 90% and one button in rest 10%..... but with the above code, It is opening in browser.

Comment: please show full code

Comment: WebView web;
 
 Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.second);
  
  web = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.web_vieww);
  web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

      Override
      public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
      {
       url="http://www.google.co.in";
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
      }
  });
 }

Comment: `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` method is called or not?

Comment: yes,,,,,, PLease see the above code. It is there....

Answer (score 0):

```
web = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.web_vieww);
web.loadUrl("http://www.google.co.in/");
web.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());

Define MyWebViewClient();

private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override

    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

        return false;
    }
}
```